# picking up one key from multiple keys having same set of values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary with following pattern

```
input_dict_data = {'how to access outlook on open network': {'intent': 'access_email_from home'},'how to access evpn': {'intent': 'access_email_from home'},'how to access ess': {'intent': 'access_email'},'how to access mobile': {'intent': 'access'}}
```

and have result list like

```
result = ['how to access outlook on open network','how to access evpn','how to access ess','how to access mobile']
```

i want to filter result list such that if intent is same for 2 results then i should retain 1st value and delete the other value

I have created one function to filter but not getting how to retain one value having similar intent field

```
def intent_matching(result_list):
    result_none = [i for i in result_list if input_dict_data[i]['intent'] is None]
    result_intent = [i for i in result_list if input_dict_data[i]['intent'] is not None]
    result = [i for i in result_intent if not any(input_dict_data[i]['intent'] == input_dict_data[item]['intent'] for item in result_intent if
               i != item)]
    result = [*result_none, *result]
    return result
```

my final result is

```
['how to access ess', 'how to access mobile']
```

and i should get the result like

```
['how to access outlook on open network','how to access ess', 'how to access mobile']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract all the intents and use a `set` to get the unique keys. Given

```py
d = {'how to access outlook on open network': {'intent': 'access_email_from home'},
     'how to access evpn': {'intent': 'access_email_from home'},
     'how to access ess': {'intent': 'access_email'},
     'how to access mobile': {'intent': 'access'}}
```

**-->** using `list` comprehensions and a slight detour of finding indices of unique elements:

```py
intents = [v['intent'] for v in d.values()]
idx_unique = sorted([intents.index(i) for i in set(intents)])
result = [list(d.keys())[idx] for idx in idx_unique]
```

**-->** or as a `for` loop version:

```py
result, seen = [], set()
for k, v in d.items():
    if not v['intent'] in seen:
        result.append(k)
    seen.add(v['intent'])
```

both options give

```
print(result)
['how to access outlook on open network', 'how to access ess', 'how to access mobile']
```